# How can I query the list of database roles in a SQL Server 2000 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, sql-server-administration

In Sql Server 2000, is it possible to return, via SQL query, a complete list of database roles that exist in a given database?

I know it is possible to see these roles by expanding the Security, Roles, and Database Roles nodes in SQL Server Management Studio, but I'd like to get them through a query that I can parse programmatically.

[image: Screenshot of the nodes in question]

To clarify, I'm not looking for a list of users with their roles, but just the list of roles themselves.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Every database in SQL Server 2000 has a [sysusers system table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260592%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Probably something like

```
Use <MyDatabase>

Select 
  [name]
From
  sysusers
Where
  issqlrole = 1
```

will do the trick

Comment: I had not realized that sysusers included roles as well as users. I checked your code and it indeed returns the correct data. Many thanks!

Comment: what a funny place to put it.

Comment: ***NB*** `sys.sysusers` is deprecated. From 2008 should be using [`sys.database_principles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187328.aspx).

Comment: ^ Should be `sys.database_principals`?

Answer (score 12):

With our SQL Server 2016 this works for me

```
Use Sandbox
Select
  name, principal_id
From
  sys.database_principals 
Where
  type = 'R' and principal_id < 16384
```

where Sandbox is the name of my database.
(I'm using SQL with ESRI ArcGIS Enterprise 10.6.)

Comment: Should `type = 'R' and principal < 16384` not be `type = 'R' and principal_id < 16384`?